# How can I make views exposed filter case-sensitive?

Tags: 8, views

When I use the exposed filter, if I search for "IMAG" all results showing image show up.  Is there a way to have the exposed filter search case sensitive?

**UPDATE**
I added a screenshot to explain more.  I have tried the operators: is equal to, contains, contains any word, contains all words, and regex.  Neither of them are case sensitive.

[image]

Comment: Aren't exposed filters case-sensitive by default? What images are you searching for? Is there a way we can reproduce this issue? Can you roughly describe how you've set up your view?

Comment: I have tried the exposed filters in Drupal 8 and none of them are case sensitive.  I am not searching for images.  I am searching for the acronym IMAG.  To reproduce: 1. Create a view for whichever content(make sure that piece of content has IMAG in the title and another that has the word "image" in the title 2. Add exposed filter for Title 3. Add acronym IMAG to exposed filter.  You will notice that it will pull up the node that has the title of "image".  I only want it to pull up the node with the title of IMAG.

Answer (score 1):

For the solution I used the [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.8.x) and used the [LIKE BINARY](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Condition.php/function/Condition%3A%3Acondition/8.9.x) operator in my condition.

```
condition('node_field_data.title', "%{$word}%", 'LIKE BINARY')
```